# GWT: getting compile-time locales list from external resource

Tags: java, gwt, localization, internationalization, locale

We need to store locales list externally in our project and just let GWT to read it at compile-time to produce permutations.

So, instead of this:

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="en_US" />    
<extend-property name="locale" values="ru_RU" /> 
<extend-property name="locale" values="fr_FR" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="es_ES" />
```

We need something like:

```
<use-property name="locale" source="../../localesList.properties" if-not-found="en_US,fr_FE,es_ES" />
```

`property-provider`s is a different thing, because they help for client to determine locale at run-time, so they will not produce those funny permutations

The worse way is to inject locale properties in `EntryPoint.gwt.xml` using some script at server-side

Do I missed something or there is no other way to make this in GWT excluding this injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd preprocess the `*.gwt.xml` file(s) and add the needed locales (say, use an ant task, and just do some dom manipulation, or even, just use a `@FILTER@` filter to do a replace), before compiling the gwt code.

Comment: So the answer is "only with preprocessing". Thank you, may be we will really use our ant builder for this.

Comment: yes. I dont think the module xml file has the feature of a #include.